# How to select return value from mysql prepared statement?

Tags: mysql, database

I am writing a stored procedure in MySQL. The following is the code I wrote:

```
SET @qry = 'SELECT id into @wid FROM work_profile where candidate_id = 1223 limit 1';
PREPARE statement FROM @qry;
EXECUTE statement;
```

However, `@wid` is null after execution.

```
SELECT id FROM work_profile where candidate_id = 1223 limit 1
```

This returns a value of 1443.

Comment: Does table work_profile contain any data? Try to execute 'SELECT id FROM work_profile'. Please show full code. How do you use @wid variable?

Comment: ...and, how do you use @wid variable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
USE test;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GETNID()
BEGIN
  SET @query = 'SELECT 100 INTO @nid';
  PREPARE statement1 FROM @query;
  EXECUTE statement1;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And to call the procedure:

```
CALL GETNUMBER();
SELECT @nid;
```

However, this does not seem to work in the MySQL Query Browser. I had to resort to using the MySQL command line client. I suspect the Query Browser clears the session after each statement.

For more EXECUTE examples, see the MySQL manual:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: You can even add that select statement, 'SELECT @nid' inside the stored procedure only, and it will give you results as expected

Answer (score 0):

The query may only return one row for use in this syntax. Either specify a `WHERE` clause which returns one row, or add `LIMIT 1`

Comment: But I added where and limit even though its returning null

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set @qry := 'test';
execute statement using @qry
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the INTO @wid from your query and add LIMIT 1.  The query will return a single row with the value you want.